# PSQL operator does not exist in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go

Here is my raw query, it works in pg_admin against the same database :

```sql
WITH myconstants (nb_pieces,nb_room,is_fiber) as (
        values (0,0,true)
 )
SELECT 
    pbuy.name, seller.name as seller_name, fiche.fiber
FROM 
    on_plan_buy pbuy
INNER JOIN
      card_fiche fiche
      ON pbuy.uuid = fiche.ad_uuid
INNER JOIN
     on_plan_seller seller
     ON pbuy.seller_id = seller.id
INNER JOIN
        myconstants conste
        ON true
WHERE pbuy.code_insee IN ('92108','75018')
        AND pbuy.price <= 9999999 AND pbuy.price >= 0
        AND CASE WHEN conste.is_fiber = false THEN true ELSE fiche.fiber = true END
LIMIT 100;
```

But when i do it in golang :

```golang
query = `
WITH myconstants (nb_pieces,nb_room,is_fiber) as (
    values ($3,$4,$5)
 )
SELECT 
    pbuy.name
FROM 
    ` + tableOnPlan + ` pbuy
INNER JOIN
    card_fiche fiche
    ON pbuy.uuid = fiche.ad_uuid
INNER JOIN
    myconstants conste
    ON true
WHERE pbuy.code_insee IN ('` + strings.Join(gsm.CodeInsee, "','") + `')
    AND pbuy.price <= $1 AND pbuy.price >= $2
    AND CASE WHEN conste.is_fiber = false THEN true ELSE fiche.fiber = true END
LIMIT 100;
`
//AND CASE WHEN conste.nb_pieces = 0 THEN pbuy.piece > 0 ELSE pbuy.piece = conste.nb_pieces END
//AND CASE WHEN conste.nb_room = 0 THEN pbuy.chambre > 0 ELSE pbuy.chambre = conste.nb_room END
//AND CASE WHEN conste.is_fiber = false THEN true ELSE fiche.fiber = true END
fmt.Println(query)
err = db.Select(&response.Offers, query, gsm.PriceMax, gsm.PriceMin, gsm.NbRoom, gsm.NbChamber, gsm.Fiber)
```

With this structure for gsm :

```golang
type GetSearchMsg struct {
    Adresse          string   `json:"adresse"`
    CodeInsee        []string `json:"code_insee"`
    M2               int      `json:"m2"`
    PriceMin         int      `json:"price_min"`
    PriceMax         int      `json:"price_max"`
    Type             string   `json:"type"`
    NbRoom           int      `json:"nb_room"`
    NbChamber        int      `json:"nb_chamber"`
    TypeConstruction string   `json:"TypeConstruction"`
    TypeTravel       string   `json:"type_travel"`
    GeoId            string   `json:"geo_id"`
    TimeTravel       string   `json:"time_travel"`
    Fiber            bool     `json:"fiber"`
}
```

i have a :

```
ERRO[0002] pq: operator does not exist: text = boolean   error=TestError
panic: pq: operator does not exist: text = boolean
```

And when i roll over gsm.fiber in my IDE it still says me that gsm.fiber is a boolean.

I may have a solution to concat the query with the string value of gsm.fiber but it's not very elegant.

Comment: Those two queries are far from being the same. I mean have you tried to run the exact same query, the one with constants and no parameters, in Go? Have you tried to run the one with parameters in pg_admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that PostgreSQL doesn't know what types the columns are in your CTE. When you say this in `pg_admin`:

```
WITH myconstants (nb_pieces,nb_room,is_fiber) as (
    values (0,0,true)
)
```

Everyone knows that `true` is a boolean so everything works. But when you use this in Go:

```
WITH myconstants (nb_pieces,nb_room,is_fiber) as (
    values ($3,$4,$5)
)
```

the driver probably doesn't know what types to use so it uses `text` for `$5` so `conste.is_fiber` has type text and `conste.is_fiber = false` ends up trying to compare `text` with `boolean`.

You should be able to get around this with some casting:

```
WITH myconstants (nb_pieces, nb_room, is_fiber) as (
    values ($3::int, $4::int, $5::boolean)
)
```